# JMeter Scripting/Execution/Monitoring of Running Test and Installation on Linux Server

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Need suggestions for Performance Testing using JMeter in Linux server.

Any difficulty/challenges for test execution and script recording and monitoring of running test on JMeter that has installed on Linux Machine.

How can we do recording using JMeter if that in Linux mode.

Answer (score 0):

As per [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) project main page:

> The Apache JMeter™ application is open source software, a **100% pure Java application** designed to load test functional behavior and measure performance.

So given you have [JDK](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html) or [Server JRE](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-server-jre8-downloads.html) version 8 or higher you should be able to run JMeter on any operating system where Java can run.

Only one advice, there can be `jmeter` package in your OS package manager, i.e. like [`jmeter` in Debian Linux](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=jmeter) which is very outdated and according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) article you should be using the latest version of JMeter so make sure to get the most up-to-date stable version from [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page

The [instruction for recording tests](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) is operating-system agnostic, it will work for any platform

Comment: Can we use purely linux mode in Linux JMeter server or Linux in Desktop mode? How can we record script and debug script in linux machine where Jmeter installed.